# I released a gas I retake my wudu but should I restart my salah I was about to finish it or do I continue to where I left. Please answer this question

Tags: salat, wudu

Do you  restart prayer after farting? Or can I pray from where I left?

Thanks for everyone who helped me I learn something new today by the help of y'all

Answer (score 1):

One of the reasons to make your prayer (*salah*) valid is to have wudu' when performing your prayers. And once you break your wudu', your prayer will no longer valid.

**Extra knowledge** : Unless you are already in the last rakaa't, finished giving your first salam and by that moment you fart, then you will not need to re-perform your prayers as it is considered as valid. Other than that scenario, your prayer is no longer valid and you cannot continue from where you left the prayer.

Wallahualam.

Comment: Please add an evidence for your "Extra Knowledge" because this is certainly not agreed upon.

Comment: @Medi1Saif Simple explanation is that, there are 13 pillars in a muslim prayers which you have to follow to make your prayers valid. One of them is "To give the first salaam". What I meant here is, once you fart after giving your first salaam, then your prayer is consider as valid as the second salaam does not include in this 13 prayers pillars.

Comment: You are quoting hanafi view, the majority view is that you can't continue a prayer if you released gas, but you must re-do it fom the start.

Answer (score 1):

If you fart, you should re-take your wudhu and pray from the beginning becuase your wudhu and prayer would have been broke